# How to add increment numbers to a new column? Using only openpyxl or without Pandas

Tags: python, list, append, openpyxl, increment

As this challenge is for me to not use pandas to achieve this result. I have tried many variations and have failed. What can I do? I am suppose to make a customer id that keeps going up as I go down the column starting with the number 320 in excel.

```
[‘A’]=“customer id”
id=[‘A:A50’]

For row in id:
For cell in row: 
    Cell.value=cell.value.append(i in range(320,370)
```

Comment: I meant [‘A1’]  and [‘A2:A50’] in the code

Comment: Use `ws.cell()` within a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take look at [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) built-in function, consider following simple example

```
letters = ['A','B','C','D','E']
for inx, letter in enumerate(letters, 101):
    print(inx, letter)
```

gives output

```
101 A
102 B
103 C
104 D
105 E
```

Second optional argument is start, `101` in example above, assumed `0` if not given.